# How to solve $X^2 = 0.4$ or $X^5 = 0.7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am studying poker theory unfortunately I am not very strong at algebra. I know what the following equations mean they are very important to determine how often the players yet to act facing a bet can respond with a specific action before the bet becomes unprofitable, but I have forgotten how to solve them. I know I can solve these by using the inverse of the original. I am just can't remember how to do that when the numbers are not whole numbers.

$X^2 = 0.4$
or
$X^5 = 0.7$

Thank you for taking the time to help

Comment: Formatting tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

For positive numbers, like you have, you can take the roots of both sides, so $$X^2=0.4\\X=0.4^{\frac 12} \approx 0.632$$ Your calculator should have an $x^y$ button.

Comment: Just a note: the $\sqrt[x]{\ }$ button comes in handy for integers.

Comment: @FrenzyLi: why for integers only ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, you're right. I checked my calculator and found that non intergers also work.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^n=t\iff x=\sqrt[n]t.$$ This can also be expressed as

$$x^n=t\iff x=t^{1/n}.$$